# What to get the actual number using call_function in jsonrpc near protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

The following query using call_function in jsonrpc in near protocol

```
http post https://rpc.testnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 id=test method=query   params:='{
    "request_type": "call_function",
    "finality": "final",
    "account_id": "dev-1591261827342",
    "method_name": "get_total_supply",
    "args_base64": "e30="
  }'
```

gives the following result:

```
{
    "id": "test",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "block_hash": "FrKNvsEbqPsdT1ijLkUBNoX3SnUQbTCXjoPj7yC2WW5i",
        "block_height": 9616038,
        "logs": [],
        "result": [
            34,
            49,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            34
        ]
    }
}
```

How to convert the result to the actual number which is '1000000000000000'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"result": [
            34,
            49,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            48,
            34
        ]
```

is an array of bytes. NEAR SDKs use JSON encoding for input and output by default, but not limited by that, so if you convert it, you get `"1000000000000000"`. Here is the Python snippet to convert it:

```py
>>> result = [34, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 34]
>>> ''.join(chr(x) for x in result)
'"1000000000000000"'
```